# UIButton label text autoshrink with insets

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibutton, resize

I am using Auto Layout. I have a UIButton with a fixed height and width and a background image (a rounded square). It displays text strings of variable length (between 1 and 30 words, let's say).

I wanted to make the text autoshrink depending on string length, and to have up to 3 lines of text in my button. So I did this:

```
 [button.titleLabel setMinimumScaleFactor:0.01];
    [button.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth: YES];
    [button.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:3];
    [button.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
```

I also set the font size to a high value like 50 in the Interface Builder. And I set the line break to "Clip".

The button's text correctly adapts to the number of characters, but it tends to go beyond the frame of the button. It does that for mid-length strings but not for huge strings and I have no idea why. I have tried to add insets to my button but it doesn't do much, only moves the overly-big text around, so I assume the font adjustment is calculated prior to the incorporation of insets.

Below a screenshot. There are 4 of those buttons, contained within the bigger blue view. The red background is the background of the button, the yellow is an image that serves as background.

[image: Screenshot]

[I uploaded an example project on Google Drive. Use iPhone 6 Plus for simulation.](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1I1Ps7PI6y0dTNLeDBpbjhsa0k&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should also set your button's `titleEdgeInsets` property.

For instance:

```
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
```

In your project, it seems that there some layout constraints that are messing with the buttons' title label.

When adding the following constraints, it works.

```
UILabel *titleLabel = button.titleLabel;
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(titleLabel);
[button addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[titleLabel]|"
                                                               options:kNilOptions
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:views]];
```

Before using this solution, I suggest you first try to set your layout constraints in a simpler way if possible.

Comment: I have done that. The example above has title insets, set using Storyboard.

Comment: I have made an example project where setting the edge insets solves it. Could you make a project with only that part to share so that I and others could try on it directly?

Comment: I have uploaded an example project in my original question. Thank you.

Comment: With your edit:
- The text fits the button and does not go beyond the button's edges, which is awesome
- The insets do not do anything. I tried removing title insets and/or content insets in the project and nothing happens

I would still like to have a "padding" or "margin" or something similar to avoid having my text stick to the button.
Also if you could explain what your constraint does, I would appreciate it, I am new to constraints and I just don't get that one! And if you have ideas for simplifying my constraints, that'd be cool too.

Thanks a lot for all your help so far.

Comment: Mimicking what you did with the constraint, I added a leading space constraint between the title label and the button, and a horizontal centering constraint. And now it seems to work! I will test further with my actual project and get back to you. Thank you.